# getting the specific string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 4.1.21 (win 32) on Windows 7.

I have a field called "path" in table "test"
some rows look like following:

```
/date/sunday/morning/
/date/sunday/morning/9
/date/wednesday/morning/11
/date/monday/morning/10
/date/monday/afternoon/
/date/friday/wholeday/10/pm
```

...etc.

I want to get all days after `/date/` till the next '/' starts for example: sunday or wednesday or morning as the results.

thank you-

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function, together with a filter based on a [pattern match](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/pattern-matching.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', 3), '/', -1)
FROM   test
WHERE  path LIKE '/date/%'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ed90/1/0).